# How do I update DESTINATION of arrows in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory, networkx

I've looked up for several possible ways to plot arrows with matplotlib (arrow, fancyarrow, annotate)

I can't find any method to set their end point, though there exists methods to set the starting point. `arrow.set_x()` for example.

What I wanna do eventually is to interactively change node positions of a graph by drag-and-dropping, while the related edges changes as well. (NetworkX draw function doesn't give a nice positioning)

So how do I change the destination of arrows in matplotlib?

> A static solution wouldn't help because I tried removing existing arrows and plotting ones with new destination, and it worked. BUT doing it in event handler crashed.

Comment: If you want to interact with the graph matplotlib may not be a good option. I would suggest that you try another [networkx output](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.html) file and use another file format and UI. For instance GraphML+yed.

Comment: @Emilien Thanks for suggestion, though that doesn't seem like an option for me at the moment.